# JScroll load Ajax content

Tags: jquery

How do I use JScroll to load an ajax content? on the site of [jscroll](http://jscroll.com/) it doesn't have any example on loading an ajax content. Can anyone assist me on this. Also if JScroll cannot do this can anyone give me a link for an Infinite scroll for Jquery?

On the Jscroll examples. Loading a second page is something like this

```
<div class="scroll">
    <h3>Page 1</h3>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <a href="example-page2.html">next page</a>
</div>
```

As you can see you have to define the 'a' tag to have an href pointing to the second page to load. But I was thinking of having to pass a function that will retrieve the content dynamically something like this

```
$('.scroll').jscroll({
    ajaxfunction: function() {
        // Return dynamic content here
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: `can anyone give me a link for an Infinite scroll for Jquery?` the first step on that journey is to Google `jquery infinite scroll`.

Comment: ... but looking at jScroll, loading content, probably through Ajax, is the very thing the plugin does, no? Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Ahh, I see. That indeed doesn't seem to be in there any more

Answer (score 1):

The ajax content is retrieved automatically from the URL defined in the `href` of the `nextSelector` element, which is the `a` tag in the example. That is all you have to do. The ajax request is made for you by the plugin.

You can also use the `callback` option to pass a function in which you can manipulate the DOM or the data returned at the end of each scroll request. The automatic loading of the next page by either scrolling or clicking is the intended behavior of the plugin, however.